# Inicializar o gráfico no matplotlib e depois inserir elementos

Tags: python, matplotlib

Olá. Existe alguma maneira de eu primeiramente abrir um gráfico com o matplotlib e, após aberto, realizar algumas operações? Ex: abrir gráfico e depois plotar uma reta, depois outra, assim por diante.

Sei que existem alguns tópicos no stackoverflow inglês sobre isso, e a solução que mais se aproxima do meu problema diz pra utilizar o

> plt.io()

e, em seguida

> plt.show()

Fiz isso, porém  o gráfico trava de tal forma que nem responde. Meu objetivo aqui é inicializar o gráfico em branco e depois traçar algumas retas.

Meu código até o momento:

```
   def startPlot():
    plt.title('Adaline')
    plt.axis([-0.2, 1.2, -0.1, 1.4])
    plt.grid()
    #plots the dots
    plt.plot([0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1], 'ro')
    plt.draw()



def printCurve(weights, bias):
    plt.title('Adaline')
    t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.001)
    f = (-weights[1] * t  - bias)/(weights[0])
    #plots the curve
    plt.plot(t, f, 'k')
    plt.draw()
```

Chamo uma vez o startPlot() e várias vezes o printCurve().Quero chamar o plt.show() antes de tudo, mas se eu fizer isso ou fizer plt.show(break=True), não plota mais nada depois disso.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que encontrei, você deve utilizar

```
plt.ion()
```

junto com

```
plt.draw()
```

tal qual [este exemplo](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/widgets/lasso_selector_demo_sgskip.html#sphx-glr-gallery-widgets-lasso-selector-demo-sgskip-py) ou [esta pergunta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874767/real-time-plotting-in-while-loop-with-matplotlib).

Infelizmente não consigo testar pois estou num python *modo texto* por enquanto. Faco um update mais tarde.